# How can i make an array of integers all relatively prime by increasing each number in minimum steps?

Tags: algorithm, primes

How can i make an array of integers all relatively prime by increasing each number in minimum steps?

Till now, i have come up this kind of strategy:
1) divide by their common multiples (say k, then each step i perform will equal k afterwards)
2) incrementing the number which is "closest" to a prime
But, i am not sure the correctness of this strategy.
Does anyone has a better idea?

For example, a[5]={2,4,6,7,8} 
the solution should be {2,5,9,7,11} in 7 moves.

Comment: Do you have some limitations on the array size and the value of the numbers?

Comment: You need to state your problem more precisely.  What do you want to minimize?  What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Thanks all of your help:) I already have solve this problem by using a modified sieve method.

Comment: This question is clearly related to the ongoing facebook HackerCup competition: https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=1420024724897316&round=1437956993099239. In the sense of a good sportsmanship, please only discuss after the competition had ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that gcd(n, n+1) = 1 for all integers n. Therefore, one possible strategy will be to take the two numbers with smallest absolute difference and make the smaller equal to `the_value_of_the_bigger_one - 1`.

By the way, I think your second strategy is incorrect. Imagine that the next prime is p. Then you can construct an array, in which all the numbers (besides that, which you are increasing) can have p as а factor. And when you increase it, the gcd of the array will be equal to p. Example array can be (24, 2, 48) -- current gcd is 2, but when you try your second strategy, the array will become (24, 3, 48), which has gcd equal to 3.

Comment: I am not sure if i should pick two with smallest absolute difference.
Can you try this on a[5]={2,4,6,7,8} as an example?

Comment: How does this extend beyond the selected 2 numbers? We can't just do the same because `gcd(n-1, n, n+1) != 1`.

Comment: @WingYip Aha, I see what you mean. You have to check first if the array gcd is already 1. Then there is only the case when there are two equal numbers. In this case, simply increment one of them.

Comment: @Dukeling `gcd(n-1, n, n+1) = gcd(n-1, gcd(n, n+1)) = gcd(n-1, 1) = 1`

Comment: @Dukeling I see what you mean. I thought the question is for the gcd of the sequence. However, the example bellow shows that it isn't...